# Disable the vertical scroll-behavior of the scrollviewer in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer, vertical-scrolling

I am using a scrollviewer to show some buttons displayed horizontally, I can use the scrollviewer to scroll from left to right, and visa versa. But the user can still drag and scroll downward, though the scrollViewer wil scroll back to the top automatically. This provides a bad UX, thus I want to disable the vertical scroll-behavior of the scrollviewer, user can just scroll horizontally. any thoughts? thanks.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="auto" Height="100" Margin="0,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="Origin_Click">
                    </Button>
<Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="Origin_Click">
                    </Button>
<Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="Origin_Click">
                    </Button>
</StackPanel>    
            </ScrollViewer>
```

v

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="disabled"`

Comment: I'm working with Windows Phone 8 and it doesn't work.

Comment: To disable vertical scrolling in scrollviewer use following:

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>

To Disable horizontal scrolling in scrollviewer use following:

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">

Answer (score 1):

For windows phone 8 and 8.1 :

To disable vertical scrolling in scrollviewer use following:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>
```

To Disable horizontal scrolling in scrollviewer use following:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
```