# Disable the scroll of the ScrollViewer for a while

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `ScrollViewer` with an `ItemPresenter` inside.
The `ItemsPresenter` contains a few dropdowns, and when I open one of those, I'd like to disable the parent `ScrollViewer`'s scroll and only re-enable it only when the dropbox is closed.
By saying "disable" I mean prevent scrolling at all (even with the mouse wheel).

I've tried to set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
   <ItemsPresenter />
</ScrollViewer>
```

but that doesn't work either.
It just hides the scrollbar, but the **mouse wheel still works**.

So, is there a way to completely disable the `ScrollViewer`'s scroll?

Here is the full code that I have:

```
<ListView.Template>
   <ControlTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsScrollEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
         <ItemsPresenter />
      </ScrollViewer>
   </ControlTemplate>
</ListView.Template>
```

P.S. There are lots of some similar questions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373778/how-can-i-disable-horizontal-scrolling-in-a-wpf-listbox) this and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459751/disable-the-vertical-scroll-behavior-of-the-scrollviewer-in-windows-phone), but none of them is the one I wanted.

Comment: Your converter probably returns **Hidden** for the visibility, but that only hides the ScrollBar, but scrolling is still possible. It should return **Disabled** instead, which prevents scrolling.

Comment: No, it was returning "Disabled". The strange thing there is that even if I hardcode "Disabled" right there (see the first sample), it still won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable scrolling by handling the `PreviewMouseWheel` event for the `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsScrollEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
              PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
   <ItemsPresenter />
</ScrollViewer>
```

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Woow, that worked! I have tried "MouseWheel" event, but wasn't aware of the "PreviewMouseWheel". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this also prevent keyboard scrolling?

Comment: @miami No, but you can handle the corresponding keys with `PreviewKey...` events, too.